# Creating CSS menu using MySQL Data

Tags: mysql

I have this menu structure:

```html
<li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I want to be able to generate it from my current table structure:

```
sequence
page_title
page_url
parent
```

In the above structure, `parent` will equal `sequence` so for all top levels, my query would include `WHERE parent = ''` then all child items, the query would include: `WHERE parent = '[SEQUENCE]'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly. You're looking to sort your menu items by parent, followed by child menu items.

For the parent items, you could make the parent column equal itself.

Ex.

```
id | sequence | page_title | page_url | parent
----------------------------------------------
1  | 1        | parent     | url      | 1
3  | 3        | child 2    | url      | 1
2  | 2        | child 1    | url      | 1
```

The query to sort the results would be:

```
SELECT * FROM menu_items ORDER BY parent, sequence
```

In your code to create the parent/child menu, you could check to see if the parent = id to determine if the item is a parent item. This help?